# No JRE found when launching android Studio - Windows 10

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I can't launch Android Studio, the problem is new and I've been using it without issue, last use was Friday so not sure what has happened between then and now. I kept getting no JRE found, and I couldn't locate a Java file in my program files. So I downloaded Java 11 from Oracle and installed it and set the `JAVA_HOME` and `JDK_HOME` variables to that file but when I launch it i get this warning error
An illegal reflective access operation has occurred

Not sure where to go from here

Comment: There is a JRE inside intsallation folder of Android Studio, set `JAVA_HOME` and `JDK_HOME` to that JRE that might solve your problem. Mine was solved

Comment: Try JDK 8 instead of JDK 11

Answer (score 1):

Please validate either ANDROID_STUDIO_JDK or JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME points to valid JDK installation

Steps of setup the JAVA PATH and after restart the android studio

1- If you do not have JDK installed download it and get it installed.

2- If Java JDK is already installed you should find it at C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.x.x_x

3- Go to Start → Computer → System Properties → Advanced System Properties → Advance → Environment Variables

4- Add new variable : Variable Name : JAVA_HOME,Variable value : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.x.x_x

5- Add (append) new system variable : Variable Name : PATH , Variable value : ;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.x.x_x\bin

if not working , you will restart the PC